# Is "QUEUE=" in /etc/sysconfig/sendmail the same as the "-q" switch in sendmail?

Tags: centos, email-server, sendmail, centos5

CentOS 5.x, SendMail 8.14.4

My Sendmail server is currently configured to retry deferred messages every hour.  In `/etc/sysconfig/sendmail` I have the following:

```
DAEMON=yes
QUEUE=1h
```

I don't see this file mentioned in the Batbook.  If I change the queue interval here (to say, `QUEUE=15m`) and restart sendmail services, would that effectively be the same as running `/usr/sbin/sendmail -q15m`?

Comment: Could you name OS/distribution you use?  AFAIK you refer to non sendmail.org  "extras".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is yes. To be absolutely accurate the final command would probably be `sendmail -bd -q15m`.

Assuming a dist based on init scripts you can always have a look at the scripts in `/etc/init.d` to see what can be set in the sysconfig file and how the commands are built up.